# How can I reproduce Apple's iOS Tint-Color Formula for Toolbar/Button gradients?

Tags: iphone, ios, colors, tint

We're looking to reproduce the way Apple applies a tint-color to their controls. We're developing a web-based product and thus have to reproduce the formula/application of the color ourselves.

Our analysis shows that its non-trivial and at the very least non-linear since some colors reproduce entirely different hues.

The prefect answer would include a formula and/or an explanation of how to calculate the gradients for the toolbar as well as the buttons on the toolbar given a Tint Color.

Comment: ...apologies for commenting 3 years later, but did this ever work for you? The link given below by @makdad is now down.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Photoshop UI Mockup design file provided by [Teehan & Lax](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/06/14/iphone-gui-psd-v4/).  They've implemented a lot of the Apple stuff using Photoshop standard layer effects, so you can resize them as vector graphics and re-tint them to suit your needs.